# Bootstrap accordion inside accordion events

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an accordion inside another accordion, and i'm trying to handle the show/hide events of the inner accordion.

The problem is that when i expand the inner accordion, there are two events which are fired, one for the inner accordion and one for the outer accordion. 
Is it possible to have an accordion inside another accordion and when i click the inner accordion only events for the inner accordion to be fired?

here is an example of my code

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group #1
              </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                This is a simple accordion inner content...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group #2 (With nested accordion inside)
              </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">

                <!-- Here we insert another nested accordion -->

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerOne">
                        Collapsible Inner Group Item #1
                      </a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche...
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerTwo">
                        Collapsible Inner Group Item #2
                      </a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseInnerTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche...
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Inner accordion ends here -->

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
                    alert('show' + $(this).attr('id'));
                });

                $('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
                    alert('hide' + $(this).attr('id'));
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After too many hours of searching i found the solution

We need to add:
event.stopPropagation();

```
   $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      alert('show' + $(this).attr('id'));
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having problems because you are using the class .container as selector. If you use the id of the accorddion, you don´t need to use stopPropagation(), because the events aren´t the same.

```
$("#collapseOne").on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    alert('show' + $(this).attr('id'));
});

$("#collapseTwo").on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    alert('show' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Hope can help!